# How to modify my SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I need to know the total number of Jobs completed by each Employee as well as the total Rate if I only have the following information.

One job can be completed by 2 different Employees.

For example, Employee A has completed 2 jobs (JobID  and JobID 2). So the total segments of Employee A is 30 segments but per jobID is different segment rate.

But I just need the total rate of all segments. SO Employee A has complete 2 jobs and a total of 90USD

```
(10 x 5 USD) + (20 x 2 USD) = 90 USD
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select 
    EmployeeID, count(distinct JobID) 
from 
    Table_name
group by 
    EmployeeID
```

But I do not know how to compute the total rate per employee.

Image of the table:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you:

```
select EmployeeID, COUNT(distinct JobID) as [Total Jobs], SUM([Segements per Job] * [Rate per Segement (USD)]) as [Total Rate (USD)]
from Table_name
Group by EmployeeID
```

**SUM([Segements per Job] * [Rate per Segement (USD)])** will multiply the segements and rate and then sum them for each employee as the query  is grouped based on EmployeeID.